# how to create button dynamically and add the onclick event for html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have created one button in my javascript code, after clicking on this button it should go to the product.html

```
var outputb2 = "<p align=right>"+ "<input type=button value=productandservices onClick=window.location=product.html>" + "</input>" +"</p>";
    $('#product').append(outputb2);
```

where product is the div id in the product.html.but when i click on this button product and services..its not going to this product.html.how can i do..?

Comment: Use quotes properly `"<input type='button' value='productandservices' onClick='window.location=product.html'>"`, However your code works http://jsfiddle.net/4F8RY/

Comment: i tried everyone suggestion but still its not working..its not going to product.html..

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need some escape characters in your code, it will work

```
var outputb2 = "<p 'align=right'>"+ "<input type='button' value='productandservices' onClick='window.location=\"product.html?someParam=hi\"'>" + "</input>" +"</p>";
$('#product').append(outputb2);
```

Comment: thanks its working ...but one thing tell me i want to pass one parameter to product .html..how can i..?

Comment: updated code added parameter to the url `?someParam=hi`

Comment: hi..actually in my first page..i m searching some list.after clicking on the list item ..i m going to the respective list items profile page.this list item name is stored in text varable.now in the profile page i m going to this product.html means it should give information of product of that merchant only .so what i have to  pass it to the url..window.location=product.html?...

Comment: if you have var `someVariable = "hi";`, you can code as `var outputb2 = "<p 'align=right'>"+ "<input type='button' value='productandservices' onClick='window.location=\"product.html?parameterName="+someVariable+"\"'>" + "</input>" +"</p>";` hopefully you need to think and try on your own

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
<script>
var outputb2 = "<p align=right>"+ "<input type=button id='productandservices' value=productandservices >" + "</input>" +"</p>";//added id
    $('#product').append(outputb2);

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        $(document).on("click","#productandservices",function()
        {
            alert('clcik');
            window.location='product.html';
        });

    });

</script>
```

or

Enclose filename in quotes `'`

```
<script>
var outputb2 = "<p align=right>"+ "<input type=button id='productandservices' value=productandservices onClick=window.location='product.html' >" + "</input>" +"</p>";
    $('#product').append(outputb2);


</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are using javascript for this, unless you are sending some data with the click event. there is a simple html code to do what you want.

```
<a href="product.html#product">product and services</a>
```

If you must use java-script try this

```
onclick="javascript:location.href='product.html#product'"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var outputb2 = "<p align=right>";
outputb2 +=  "<input type='button' value='productandservices' onClick='window.location=product.html'>"
outputb2 += "</p>";

$('#product').append(outputb2);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var outputb2 = "<p align='right'><input type='button' value='productandservices' onClick='window.location=product.html'></input></p>";
$('#product').append(outputb2);
```

Comment: Please provide explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var outputb2 = "<p align='right'>"+ 
                 "<input type='button' value='productandservices 'onClick='window.location=\"product.html\"' />" + 
               "</p>";
$('#product').append(outputb2);
```

Add `'`  like this : `onClick='window.location=\"product.html\"'`

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/2hNd9/3/)

Answer (score 2):

right syntax to use:

```
<input TYPE="button" value=productandservices onclick="window.location.href='http://www.wherever.com'">
```

Another option is to create a link in the button:

```
<button type="button"><a href="yourlink.com">Link link</a></button>
```

Then use CSS to style the link and button, so that the link takes up the entire space within the button (so there's no miss-clicking by the user):

```
button, button a{position:relative;}
button a{top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;}
```

but the point of a link is to go to another page. So trying to make a button act like a link is the wrong solution. My suggestion is that you should use a link and style it to look like a button.

```
<a href="/page2>Continue</a>
```